# I want to add a custom Middleware to check any script in POST request, how to do that?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I want to check whether the POST request coming from various user input forms in my application contains any MALICIOUS CODE script or HTML tags if any found I want to redirect back to the form page and display a message that these script characters are not allowed. I can check for this functionality in the controller but I want to do this with middleware, how to do that, can anyone help me??

Please note, I am just a beginner, not that expert, so please forgive me for any errors in question or logic.

The expected result is that, I want to check on form submit that any input field contains any script tags or not? and I want to achieve this via MIDDLEWARE so that I can just include this middleware on requests i want to check.

Comment: Vishal please read the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware and try before asking question .if you still get error then post it in stackoverflow so that some one will answer to your question.thanks

Comment: ```$this->validate(request(), [
                'input_name' =>  'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z]+$/u|max:255',
            ]);
```
Try this

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i want to check for each and every input fields on post request. your code will work on one input field input_name.

Comment: if you're worried about XSS attack or SQL injection, Laravel is automatically checking these things and you can feel comfortable about this kind of attacks

Comment: Laravel out of the box does what you want, it check for those characters and try to escape them before sending them to database but if at all you will not like to have them in your database, you can still achieve such using middleware but first have to match those characters with regular expression and then return the post back to the user.

Comment: Thanks, I have added some <script> in the input box like js alert script, laravel is saving the script as it is, and when i am viewing that data in the admin panel, the script is executing... I don't want such behavior. 
I have used strip_tags() function to strip any tags in user input data. but now i want to acheive this functionality via middleware

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following to check input coming from POST or GET.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $this->checkRequest($request);

    $response = $next($request);

    return $response;
}

private function checkRequest($request)
{
    print_r($request->all());

    // you can check for request method here as well
    // $request->isMethod('POST') etc
    // ofcourse i am not checking for malicious code you can do that much better or loop through request parameters thats upto you 

    if ($request->has('some') && $this->isMalicious($request->get('some'))) {
        return redirect()->route('go/home')->with(['message' => 'found some in request']);
    }
}

private function isMalicious($input)
{
     if ($input == 'something') return true;

     return false;
}
```

How to make a middleware and how to assign it to certain routes or groups or globally can be found here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#global-middleware